# How to simulate daily stock returns in R

Tags: r

I need to simulate a stock's daily returns. I am given `r=(P(t+1)-P(t))/P(t)` (normal distribution) mean of µ=1% and sd of σ =5%. P(t) is the stock price at end of day t. Simulate 100,000 instances of such daily returns.

Since I am a new R user, how do I setup t for this example. I am assuming P should be setup as:

```
P <- rnorm(100000, .01, .05)
r=(P(t+1)-P(t))/P(t)
```

Comment: `r=(P(t+1)-P(t))/P(t)` is supposed to be the formula for the return (it's just proportion chnage).. You would need P1 and P2  (representing t and t+1).  and then calculate r based on those two vectors.  Your second line is not in R format at all.

Comment: how do i set that up if t+1 and t are not binary?

Comment: Here is the complete answer below.

Comment: t is time, it is not binary. You have two time periods, you are calculating the proportion change over those two time period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you already have an answer and ColonelBeauvel might have more domain knowledge than I (assuming this is business or finance homework.) I approached it a bit differently and am going to post a commented transcript. His method uses the `<<-` operator which is considered as a somewhat suspect strategy in R, although I must admit it seems quite elegant in this application. I suspect my method will probably be a lot faster if you ever get into doing large scale simulations.

Starting with your code:

```
P <- rnorm(100000, .01, .05)
 # r=(P(t+1)-P(t))/P(t)  definition, not R code
 # inference: P_t+1 = r_t*P_t + P_t = P_t*(1+r_t)
 # So, all future P's will be determined by P_1 and r_t
```

Since P_2 will be P_1*(1+r_1)r_1 then P_3 will be P_1*(1+r_1)*(1+r_2), .i.e a continued product of the vector `(1+r)` for which there is a vectorized function.

```
 P <- P_1*cumprod(1+r)
#Error: object 'P_1' not found
 P_1 <- 100
 P <- P_1*cumprod(1+r)
#Error: object 'r' not found
# So the random simulation should have been for `r`, not P
r <- rnorm(100000, .01, .05)
P <- P_1*cumprod(1+r)
plot(P)
#Error in plot.window(...) : infinite axis extents [GEPretty(-inf,inf,5)]
 str(P)
```

This occurred because the cumulative product went above the limits of numerical capacity and got assigned to `Inf` (infinity). Let's be a little more careful:

```
 r <- rnorm(300, .01, .05)
 P <- P_1*cumprod(1+r)
 plot(P)
```

[image]

This strategy  below iteratively updates the price at time t as 'temp' and multiplies it it by a single value. It's likely to be a lot slower.

```
r = rnorm(100000, .01/252, .005)
factor = 1 + r
temp   = 100
P = c(100, sapply(1:300, function(u){
      p = factor[u]*temp
      temp<<-p
      p
     }))

> system.time( {r <- rnorm(10000, .01/250, .05)
+  P <- P_1*cumprod(1+r)
+  })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.001   0.000   0.002 
> system.time({r = rnorm(10000, .01/252, .05)
+ factor = 1 + r
+ temp   = 100
+ P = c(100, sapply(1:300, function(u){
+      p = factor[u]*temp
+      temp<<-p
+      p
+ }))})
   user  system elapsed 
  0.079   0.004   0.101
```

Comment: It is maths and dynamics of some processes, which have nothing to do with finance at first ;) However, not a lot of people answer to questions where some analysis is needed on stackoverflow...since these kind of questions are at the limit of stack.exchange!
+1 for cumprod!

Comment: what if the initial price P_1 is not given? What would P_1 become?

Comment: Anything you want it to be.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting it wrong: from what you wrote, the `mean` and the `sd` applies on the `return` and not on the `price`. I furthermore make the assumption that the `mean` is set for an annual basis (`1%` rate of return from one day to another is just ...huge!) and `t` moves along a day range of `252` days per year.

With these hypothesis, you can get a series of daily return in `R` with:

```
r = rnorm(100000, .01/252, .005)
```

Assuming the model you mentioned, you can get the serie of the prices P (containing 100001 elements, I will take `P[1]=100` - change it with your own value if needed):

```
factor = 1 + r
temp   = 100
P = c(100, sapply(1:100000, function(u){
     p = factor[u]*temp
     temp<<-p
     p
}))
```

Your configuration for the return price you mention (`mean=0.01` and `sd=0.05`) will however lead to exploding stock price (unrealistic model and parameters). Be carefull to check that `prod(rate)` will not return `Inf` .

Here is the result for the first `1000` values of `P`, representing `4` years:

```
plot(1:1000, P[1:1000])
```

[image]

One of the classical model (which does not mean this model is realistic) assumes the observed `log return` are following a normal distribution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. One more question, in the function you created, how would I determine the difference in the daily returns?

Comment: difference of the daily return or difference in the price? For the daily return just by r[-1] - head(r,-1)

Comment: the log difference of the daily

Comment: Hi , I am sorry, it's very unclear. Can you formulate in your question, using some mathematics/code notation? maybe you refer to log(P(t+1)/P(t)) ?
Btw, if the answer is satisfying, you can use the checkmark to close the topic!

Answer (score 1):

To simulate a log return of the daily stock, use the following method:

1. Consider working with 256 days of daily stock return data.
2. Load the original data into R
3. Create another data.frame for simulating Log return.
4. Code:

   ```
   logr <- data.frame(Date=gati$Date[1:255], Shareprice=gati$Adj.Close[1:255], LogReturn=log(gati$Adj.Close[1:251]/gati$Adj.Close[2:256]))
   ```

   - `gati` is the dataset
   - `Date` and `Adj.close` are the variables
   - notice the `[]` values.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> P <- rnorm(100000, .01, .05)
> r=(P(t+1)-P(t))/P(t)
> ```
>
> second line translates directly into :

```
r <- (P[-1] - P[length(P)]) / P[length(P)] # (1:5)[-1] gives 2:5
```

Answer (score 0):

Stock returns are not normally distributed for Simple Returns ("R"), given their -1 lower bound per compounded period. However, Log Returns ("r") generally are. The below is adapted from @42's post above. There don't seem to be any solutions to simulating from Log Mean ("Expected Return") and Log Stdev ("Risk") in #Rstats, so I've included them here for those looking for "Monte Carlo Simulation using Log Expected Return and Log Standard Deviation"), which are normally distributed, and have no lower bound at -1. Note: from this single example, it would require looping over thousands of times to simulate a portfolio--i.e., stacking 100k plots like the below and averaging a single slice to calculate a portfolio's average expected return at a chosen forward month. The below should give a good basis for doing so.

```
startPrice = 100
forwardPeriods = 12*10 # 10 years * 12 months with Month-over-Month E[r]
factor = exp(rnorm(forwardPeriods, .04, .10)) # Monthly Expected Ln Return = .04 and Expected Monthly Risk = .1

temp  = startPrice
P = c(startPrice, sapply(1:forwardPeriods, function(u){p = factor[u]*temp; temp <<- p; p}))
plot(P, type = "b", xlab = "Forward End of Month Prices", ylab = "Expected Price from Log E[r]", ylim = c(0,max(P)))
```

[image]

```
n <- length(P)
logRet <- log(P[-1]/P[-n])
# Notice, with many samples this nearly matches our initial log E[r] and stdev(r)
mean(logRet)
# [1] 0.04540838
sqrt(var(logRet))
# [1] 0.1055676
```

If tested with a negative log expected return, the price should not fall below zero. The other examples, will return negative prices with negative expected returns. The code I've shared here can be tested to confirm that negative prices do not exist in the simulation.

```
min(P)
# [1] 100
max(P)
# [1] 23252.67
```

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal axis is number of days, and vertical axis is price.

```
n_prices <- 1000
volatility <- 0.2
amplitude <- 10
chng <- amplitude * rnorm(n_prices, 0, volatility)
prices <- cumsum(chng)
plot(prices, type='l')
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1rax.png]